# Why doesn't Python have a sign function?

Tags: python, language-design

I can't understand why Python doesn't have a `sign` function. It has an `abs` builtin (which I consider `sign`'s sister), but no `sign`.

In python 2.6 there is even a `copysign` function (in [math](http://docs.python.org/library/math.html#math.copysign)), but no sign. Why bother to write a `copysign(x,y)` when you could just write a `sign` and then get the `copysign` directly from `abs(x) * sign(y)`? The latter would be much more clear: x with the sign of y, whereas with copysign you have to remember if it's x with the sign of y or y with the sign of x!

Obviously `sign(x)` does not provide anything more than `cmp(x,0)`, but it would be much more readable that this too (and for a greatly readable language like python, this would have been a big plus).

If I were a python designer, I would been the other way arond: no `cmp` builtin, but a `sign`. When you need `cmp(x,y)`, you could just do a `sign(x-y)` (or, even better for non-numerical stuff, just a x>y - of course this should have required `sorted` accepting a boolean instead of an integer comparator). This would also be more clear: positive when `x>y` (whereas with `cmp` you have to remember the convention positive when the **first** is *bigger*, but it could be the other way around). Of course `cmp` makes sense in its own for other reasons (e.g. when sorting non-numerical things, or if you want the sort to be stable, which is not possible using with simply a boolean)

So, the question is: why did the Python designer(s) decide to leave the `sign` function out of the language? Why the heck bother with `copysign` and not its parent `sign`?

Am I missing something?

EDIT - after Peter Hansen comment. 
Fair enough that you didn't use it, but you didn't say what you use python for. In 7 years that I use python, I needed it countless times, and the last is the straw that broke the camel's back!

Yes, you can pass cmp around, but 90% of the times that I needed to pass it was in an idiom like 
`lambda x,y: cmp(score(x),score(y))` that would have worked with sign just fine.

Finally, I hope you agree that `sign` would be more useful than `copysign`, so even if I bought your view, why bother about defining that in math, instead of sign? How can copysign be so much useful than sign?

Comment: "Am I missing something?"  If nothing else, the fact that using `sign(x-y)` requires an expression be evaluated, which means you can't pass it in as a callback unless you wrap it in a "partial" first.  With cmp() as defined, you just pass a reference to `cmp` around.  Also "incredibly useful"?  I doubt it.  I've had a need for that once in 10 years of writing Python.  If it were really so useful, I think it would be there...

Comment: @dmazzoni: wouldn't this argument work for all the questions on this site? just close stackoverflow and ask every question to the relevant topic dev or user mailing list!

Comment: @davide: First I agree, a signum function is common and useful. Secondly, I agree with dmazzoni in that your question is better asked on python-dev. It is one thing to ask how to use a list comprehension to do xyz: we can do a good job answering that here. But asking why Guido Van Rossum left out signum is tough for anyone here to answer.

Comment: The proper place for a question is any place where it's likely to be answered. Thus, stackoverflow is a proper place.

Comment: @Davide, I've used Python for just about every form of software there is, literally.  I just don't work exclusively in an area where sign() would be so useful.  You appear to; the developers clearly do not.  As has been noted, if you really want the answer, go ask where the developers themselves hang out, and you'll get an earful.

Comment: -1: @Davide: "Why" and "why not" questions generally cannot be answered here.  Since most of the principals of Python development don't answer questions here, you're rarely (if ever) going to get an answer to a "why" or "why not" question.  Further, you don't have a problem to solve.  You sound like you have a rant.  If you have a problem ("How do I work around the lack of sign in this example...") that's sensible.  "Why not" isn't sensible for this venue.

Comment: Since you're asking why someone designed something a particular way, why don't you ask the designer directly? Trying to get others to speculate isn't particularly useful.

Comment: The question might be a little emotional, but I don't think it's a bad question.  I'm sure lots of people have looked for a built-in sign function, so it can be curious why there isn't one.

Comment: This is a perfectly objective question: “Why” Python lacks any given feature is a legitimate query about the history of language design that can be answered by linking to the appropriate discussion from python-dev or other forums (sometimes blog posts) where the Python core developers happen to hash a topic out. Having tried to Google for bits of history in python-dev myself before, I can understand why a newcomer to the language might hit a dead end and come ask here in the hopes of a more experienced Python person answering!

Answer (score 340, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Indeed there was a [patch](http://bugs.python.org/msg58786) which included `sign()` in [math](http://docs.python.org/library/math.html#math.copysign), but it wasn't accepted, because they didn't agree on [what it should return in all the edge cases](http://bugs.python.org/msg59137) (+/-0, +/-nan, etc)

So they decided to implement only copysign, which (although more verbose) can be [used to delegate to the end user the desired behavior for edge cases](http://bugs.python.org/msg59154) - which [sometimes might require the call to `cmp(x,0)`](http://bugs.python.org/msg59152).

---

I don't know why it's not a built-in, but I have some thoughts.

```
copysign(x,y):
Return x with the sign of y.
```

Most importantly, `copysign` is a superset of `sign`!  Calling `copysign` with x=1 is the same as a `sign` function.  So you could just use `copysign` and *forget about it*.

```
>>> math.copysign(1, -4)
-1.0
>>> math.copysign(1, 3)
1.0
```

If you get sick of passing two whole arguments, you can implement `sign` this way, and it will still be compatible with the IEEE stuff mentioned by others:

```
>>> sign = functools.partial(math.copysign, 1) # either of these
>>> sign = lambda x: math.copysign(1, x) # two will work
>>> sign(-4)
-1.0
>>> sign(3)
1.0
>>> sign(0)
1.0
>>> sign(-0.0)
-1.0
>>> sign(float('nan'))
-1.0
```

Secondly, usually when you want the sign of something, you just end up multiplying it with another value.  And of course that's basically what `copysign` does.

So, instead of:

```
s = sign(a)
b = b * s
```

You can just do:

```
b = copysign(b, a)
```

And yes, I'm surprised you've been using Python for 7 years and think `cmp` could be so easily removed and replaced by `sign`!  Have you never implemented a class with a `__cmp__` method?  Have you never called `cmp` and specified a custom comparator function?

In summary, I've found myself wanting a `sign` function too, but `copysign` with the first argument being 1 will work just fine.  I disagree that `sign` would be more useful than `copysign`, as I've shown that it's merely a subset of the same functionality.

Comment: Using `[int(copysign(1, zero)) for zero in (0, 0.0, -0.0)]` gives `[1, 1, -1]`. That should have been `[0, 0, 0]` according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function

Comment: You have the order wrong. [int(copysign(zero, 1)) for zero in (0, 0.0, -0.0)] gives the [0,0,0] you're looking for.

Comment: @Andrew - @user238424's calling order is correct. `copysign(a,b)` returns a with the sign of b - b is the varying input, a is the value to normalize to with b's sign.  In this case, the commenter is illustrating that copysign(1,x) as a replacement for sign(x) fails, since it returns 1 for x=0, whereas sign(0) would evaluate to 0.

Comment: Floats hold "sign" separate from "value"; -0.0 is a negative number, even if that seems an implementation error.  Simply using `cmp()` will give the desired results, probably for nearly every case anyone would care about: `[cmp(zero, 0) for zero in (0, 0.0, -0.0, -4, 5)]` ==> `[0, 0, 0, -1, 1]`.

Comment: `s = sign(a) b = b * s` is not equivalent to `b = copysign(b, a)`! It does not consider the sign of b. E.g. if `a=b=-1` the first code will return 1 while the second returns -1

Comment: Seeing the false sign() replacement definition, the false equivalent for multiplication with sign(a), the false explanation for the motivation of copysign, and the correct replacement "cmp(x, 0)" being already mentioned in the question - there is not much info and it is unclear to me why this is the "accepted" answer with so many votes.?

Comment: I've never seen a sign function where `sign(0) == 1`. That doesn't seem like it follows any convention I've heard of.

Comment: @Brionius in analysis of data it might occur - "reaching zero from the positive or negative side". - Though for those we have complete different library instead of `math`.

Comment: `sign(0) == 1` is totally wrong

Comment: How do you make `sign(0) == 0` ?

Answer (score 81):

`copysign()` is defined by IEEE 754, and part of the C99 specification. That's why it's in Python. The function cannot be implemented in full by `abs(x) * sign(y)` because of how it's supposed to handle `NaN` values.

```
>>> import math
>>> math.copysign(1, float("nan"))
1.0
>>> math.copysign(1, float("-nan"))
-1.0
>>> math.copysign(float("nan"), 1)
nan
>>> math.copysign(float("nan"), -1)
nan
>>> float("nan") * -1
nan
>>> float("nan") * 1
nan
>>>
```

That makes `copysign()` a more useful function than `sign()`.

As to specific reasons why IEEE's `signbit(x)` is not available in standard Python, I don't know. I can make assumptions, but it would be guessing.

The math module itself uses `copysign(1, x)` as a way to check if `x` is negative or non-negative. For most cases dealing with mathematical functions that seems more useful than having a `sign(x)` which returns `1`, `0`, or `-1` because there's one less case to consider. For example, the following is from Python's `math` module:

```
static double
m_atan2(double y, double x)
{
    if (Py_IS_NAN(x) || Py_IS_NAN(y))
        return Py_NAN;
    if (Py_IS_INFINITY(y)) {
        if (Py_IS_INFINITY(x)) {
            if (copysign(1., x) == 1.)
                /* atan2(+-inf, +inf) == +-pi/4 */
                return copysign(0.25*Py_MATH_PI, y);
            else
                /* atan2(+-inf, -inf) == +-pi*3/4 */
                return copysign(0.75*Py_MATH_PI, y);
        }
        /* atan2(+-inf, x) == +-pi/2 for finite x */
        return copysign(0.5*Py_MATH_PI, y);
```

There you can clearly see that `copysign()` is a more effective function than a three-valued `sign()` function.

You wrote:

> If I were a python designer, I would been the other way around: no `cmp` builtin, but a `sign`.

That means you don't know that `cmp()` is used for things besides numbers. `cmp("This", "That")` cannot be implemented with a `sign()` function.

**Edit to collate my additional answers elsewhere**:

You base your justifications on how `abs()` and `sign()` are often seen together. As the C standard library does not contain a `sign(x)` function of any sort, I don't know how you justify your views. There's an `abs(int)` and `fabs(double)` and `fabsf(float)` and `fabsl(long)` but no mention of `sign()`. There is `copysign()` and `signbit()` but those only apply to IEEE 754 numbers.

With complex numbers, what would sign(-3+4j) return in Python, were it to be implemented? `abs(-3+4j)` return 5.0. That's a clear example of how `abs()` can be used in places where `sign()` makes no sense.

Suppose `sign(x)` were added to Python, as a complement to `abs(x)`. If  `x` is an instance of a user-defined class which implements the `__abs__(self)` method then `abs(x)` will call `x.__abs__()`. In order to work correctly, to handle `abs(x)` in the same way then Python will have to gain a `__sign__(x)` slot.

This is excessive for a relatively unneeded function. Besides, why should `sign(x)` exist and `nonnegative(x)` and `nonpositive(x)` not exist? My snippet from Python's math module implementation shows how `copysign(x, y)` can be used to implement `nonnegative()`, which a simple `sign(x)` cannot do.

Python should have better support for IEEE 754/C99 math functions. That would add a `signbit(x)` function, which would do what you want in the case of floats. It would not work for integers or complex numbers, much less strings, and it wouldn't have the name you are looking for.

You ask "why", and the answer is "`sign(x)` isn't useful." You assert that it is useful. Yet your comments show that you do not know enough to be able to make that assertion, which means you would have to show convincing evidence of its need. Saying that NumPy implements it is not convincing enough. You would need to show cases of how existing code would be improved with a `sign()` function.

And that it outside the scope of StackOverflow. Take it instead to one of the Python lists.

Comment: Well, I don't if that will make you happy, but Python 3 has neither `cmp()` nor `sign()` :-)

Comment: writing a good sign() function that would work properly with IEEE 754 is not trivial. This would be a good point to include it in the language, rather than leaving it out, even though I didn't elaborate this point in the question

Comment: Your comment about how "if you want the sort to be stable" means you also don't know how stable sort works. Your statement that copysign and sign are equivalent show that you didn't know much about IEEE 754 math before this post. Should Python implement all of the 754 math functions in core? What should it do for non-C99 compilers? Non-754 platforms? "isnonnegative" and "isnonpositive" are also useful functions. Should Python also include those? abs(x) defers to x.__abs__(), so should sign(x) defer to x.__sign__() ? There's little demand or need for it, so why should it be stuck into core?

Comment: math.copysign(1, float("-nan")) returns 1.0 instead of -1.0 when I try it in 2.7

Comment: The sign or signum function is a standard mathematical function defined as sign(z) = z/|z|. Its meaning for complex numbers is well-defined; just use that same definition with the complex version of division and absolute value. The result is a complex number whose magnitude is 1; e.g. sign(-3+4j) is -0.6+0.8j.  I don't see how the function's absence in C is relevant to its absence from Python. It exists in Microsoft BASIC; does that matter?

Answer (score 65):

Another one liner for sign()

```
sign = lambda x: (1, -1)[x<0]
```

If you want it to return 0 for x = 0:

```
sign = lambda x: x and (1, -1)[x<0]
```

Comment: why? The question itself acknowledges that `cmp(x, 0)` is equivalent to `sign`, and `lambda x: cmp(x, 0)` is more readable than what you suggest.

Comment: Indeed, I was wrong. I had assumed that 'cmp' was specified to return -1,0,+1, but I see that the spec does not guarantee that.

Comment: Is there any advantage to using lists instead of `-1 if x < 0 else 1`?

Comment: `sign = lambda x: -1 if x < 0 else 1` is **15% faster**. Same with `sign = lambda x: x and (-1 if x < 0 else 1)`.

Comment: I've checked various examples. If you consider suggestion from @MateenUlhaq, it is fastest sign function with -1, 0, 1 returns.

Answer (score 53):

Since `cmp` has been [removed](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html), you can get the same functionality with

```
def cmp(a, b):
    return (a > b) - (a < b)

def sign(a):
    return (a > 0) - (a < 0)
```

It works for `float`, `int` and even `Fraction`. In the case of `float`, notice `sign(float("nan"))` is zero.

Python doesn't require that comparisons return a boolean, and so coercing the comparisons to bool() protects against allowable, but uncommon implementation:

```
def sign(a):
    return bool(a > 0) - bool(a < 0)
```

Comment: For the record, this implementation returns -1 if a < 0, 0 if a = 0, and 1 if x > 0 as per the [definition on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function).

Answer (score 27):

The [definition on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) reads:

[image: sign definition]

Hence, in order to be compliant with the definition:

```
sign = lambda x: -1 if x < 0 else (1 if x > 0 else (0 if x == 0 else NaN))
```

Which for all intents and purposes may be simplified to:

```
sign = lambda x: -1 if x < 0 else (1 if x > 0 else 0)
```

This function definition [**executes fast**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16726462/2192488) and yields **guaranteed [correct results for 0, 0.0, -0.0, -4 and 5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1986776/2192488)** (see comments to other incorrect answers).

Note that [zero (0) is neither positive nor negative](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Zero.html).

Comment: This answer illustrates how succinct yet powerful python can be.

Comment: @JürgenStrobel I know exactly what you mean and I have also long been contemplating this issue. I extended the answer now for correct formalism, whilst maintaining the simplified version for most use cases.

Comment: (a > 0) - (a < 0) also complies.

Comment: @PaulCrowley Very nice! You should write your own answer and explain how this works.

Comment: Three answers are based on (a > 0) - (a < 0).

Answer (score 23):

numpy has a sign function, and gives you a bonus of other functions as well.  So:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.sign(y)
```

Just be careful that the result is a numpy.float64:

```
>>> type(np.sign(1.0))
<type 'numpy.float64'>
```

For things like json, this matters, as json does not know how to serialize numpy.float64 types.  In that case, you could do:

```
float(np.sign(y))
```

to get a regular float.

Answer (score 14):

Try running this, where x is any number

```
int_sign = bool(x > 0) - bool(x < 0)
```

The coercion to bool() handles the [possibility](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) that the comparison operator doesn't return a boolean.

Comment: Good idea, but I think you mean: int_sign = int(x > 0) - int(x < 0)

Comment: I mean: int_sign = lambda x: (x > 0) - (x < 0)

Comment: @yucer no, he really meant the cast to bool (which is a subclass of int anyway), because of the theoretical possibility of which he gave the link to the explanation.

Comment: The only downside of this construct is that the argument appears twice, which is fine only if it's a single variable

Answer (score 11):

It just doesn't.

The best way to fix this is:

```
sign = lambda x: bool(x > 0) - bool(x < 0)
```

This `sign` function returns 1 for positive values, -1 for negative values and 0 for 0.0 and -0.0 (and NaNs...).

Comment: I'll pick your solution. Although mathematically irrelevant, it is more readable.

Answer (score 10):

In Python 2, `cmp()` returns an integer: there's no requirement that the result be -1, 0, or 1, so `sign(x)` is not the same as `cmp(x,0)`.

In Python 3, `cmp()` has been removed in favor of rich comparison.  For `cmp()`, Python 3 [suggests this](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html):

```
def cmp(a, b):
    return (a > b) - (a < b)
```

which is fine for cmp(), but again can't be used for sign() because the comparison operators need not return [booleans](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__).

To deal with this possibility, the comparison results must be coerced to booleans:

```
 def sign(x):
    return bool(x > 0) - bool(x < 0)
```

This works for any `type` which is totally ordered (including special values like `NaN` or infinities).

Answer (score 7):

Yes a correct [`sign()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) function should be at least in the math module - as it is in numpy. Because one frequently needs it for math oriented code.

But `math.copysign()` is also useful independently.

`cmp()` and `obj.__cmp__()` ... have generally high importance independently. Not just for math oriented code. Consider comparing/sorting tuples, date objects, ...

The dev arguments at http://bugs.python.org/issue1640 regarding the omission of `math.sign()` are odd, because:

- There is no separate `-NaN`
- `sign(nan) == nan`  without worry (like `exp(nan)` )
- `sign(-0.0) == sign(0.0) == 0` without worry
- `sign(-inf) == -1` without worry

-- as it is in numpy

Answer (score 0):

You dont need one, you can just use:

```
if not number == 0:
    sig = number/abs(number)
else:
    sig = 0
```

Or create a function as described by others:

```
sign = lambda x: bool(x > 0) - bool(x < 0)

def sign(x):
    return bool(x > 0) - bool(x < 0)
```

Comment: It bears pointing out that `x / abs(x)` takes slightly longer than just chaining `if/else` to check which side of 0 the variable is on, or for that matter using the slimy-yet-satisfying `return (x > 0) - (x < 0)` to subtract `bool` values and return an `int`

Comment: Python treats `True` and `False` as `1` and `0`, you can absolutely do this and get either `1`, `0`, or `-1`. `def sign(x): return (x > 0) - (x < 0)` won't return a `bool`, it'll return an `int` - if you pass `0` you'll get `0` back

Comment: This is the only solution that works correctly for complex values.

Answer (score 0):

Many cases listed in other answers overlook special cases (+/-0) or make assumption that sign(-0.0) == sign(0.0).  It may be naïve, but with current implementation of IEEE we already have -0.0 == 0.0 and having sign() would allow us to disambiguate between the two.

Example provided by FogleBird seems to be best definition so far as it seems to handle +/- 0, INFINITY and NaN.