# General formula for program?

Tags: python, math

Can any one help to get the general formula, when i=1 it should be zero('0') for other numbers(2,3,4....5) it should be one('1'). 'i' starts from 1.Please someone help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Need this general formula for the program in python.

Comment: Erm... is `i = i == 1 ? 0 : i` classic not relevant here?

Comment: @Rupak: I tried there but i didnt get.

Comment: @Delwin Then why `mathematica` is mentioned in tags, but `python` is not?

Comment: @raina77ow: I have some printing lines before this so i need formula not condition. I have put condition already.

Comment: @Delvin Well, (i == 1 ? 0 : 1) is a template expression; you can use it just as you use (2 * i), for example. And, may I say, if you need to (heavily) modify the value you print right when you print it, you're doing it wrong already.

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far?

Comment: Do "other numbers" include 0, -1, -2, ...?  sgn(i-1) returns a ternary-valued step function, i>1 returns a binary-valued step function, and i != 1 returns an impulse, as does abs(sgn(i-1)).  Which do you want?  (See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986152/why-python-doesnt-have-a-sign-function)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 result = (i != 1) ? 1 : 0
```

seems there is some ambiguity as to what language you are using but anything that supports the ternary operator will work in this way you just may have to tweak the syntax.

If you cant access ternary operators then pseudo-code is

```
 result = 1;
 if (i == 1) {
     result = 0;
 }
```

In python this would be

```
result = 1
if i == 1:
    result = 0
```

Comment: @Delwin see edit - i believe this is the right python syntax

Comment: The Python syntax should work.  Python also has a ternary syntax, so `result = 0 if i == 1 else 1` would work too.

Answer (score 0):

If mathematica, then `sgn(i-1)` would be enough. See also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function).

Comment: The 'code' here is not Mathematica. In truth, *If Mathematica then *`sgn(i-1)` *will generate an error*.

Comment: There is no code here. I provided generic mathematical formula to calculate what OP required - maybe I confused tags, but for me term 'mathematica' means just math, not any programming environment.

Comment: `sgn(i-1)` is no more 'generic mathematical formula` than it is Mathematica.

Comment: I don't understand, what is your problem with sign function. This function returns required result for given arguments set (integers starting from 1) and corresponds to tag ('math') which OP used. Sure this is not code, but OP asked 'Can any one help to get the general formula'...

Comment: HPM, my CRC handbook has been in the basement for 40 years (so I can't look it up at work), but as I recall "sgn(i-1)" is in fact as generic a mathematical expression as "abs(i-1)".  The OP cited Wikipedia which says the same thing.  If you disagree then edit the Wikipedia article, and be prepared to be reverted.