# Python assign sign of number to variable

Tags: python, function, if-statement, sign, built-in

I have a variable of type int, it's Python, so it can be positive and negative. Now, I want to make another variable have the same sign as the first variable1. It's easy to do this by using an if statement and then assign -1 or +1 to a variable and multiply every variable I want to have this sign by the -1 or +1. But then I thought maybe there is another way to do this (e.g. a built-in function). Is there something like "sign = getsignbit(value)"?

edit:
Solved! math.copysign did the thing, cmp(x,0) works too, but I don't only want -1, 0 or 1, but also turn a 5 into -5.

Comment: sign = lambda x: math.copysign(1, x) looks good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built in `sign` function (see this answer for some explanation: [Why doesn't Python have a sign function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986152/why-python-doesnt-have-a-sign-function) ), but `math.copysign` might be useful to you.
http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.copysign

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a built-in function, but you can roll your own easily enough:

```
def the_sign(num):
    return cmp(num, 0)
```

Comment: Note that [`cmp` has been removed in Python3](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons).

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7, it works both but I like math.copysign better. I still gave a +1 though ;)