# Getting negative number after % division

Tags: class, python-3.x, oop

I need to get negative number after division by `%` operator.
There is a new class that I created. It gets duration of process in milliseconds and represents it in seconds, minutes, hours and days.
In case of negative input,  it should represent negative value of duration. 
I made method for representing seconds.

```
    class Duration:
        def __init__(self, milliseconds: int):
            self.__milliseconds = int(milliseconds)

        def seconds(self):
            return abs(self.__milliseconds) // 1000 % 60 * self.is_negative()

        def is_negative(self):
            return -1 if self.__milliseconds < 0 else 1
```

The function `is_negative()` helps return negative value after `%` division. Otherwise I get 1 after % divison, and it disrupts my **add**() calculation. Like `Duration(1000)-Duration(3000)` or etc.

**Is there more convinient way for getting seconds value in case of negative milliseconds value?**

Comment: try this return  self._milliseconds < 0 ? -1 : 1

Comment: That is not valid syntax in Python @SumitDhariwal.

Comment: `math.copysign`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986152/why-doesnt-python-have-a-sign-function

Comment: @SumitDhariwal in Python that is invalid syntax, the ternary operator is like OP posted

Comment: I don't understand the need for `% 60` as you get incorrect values for anything above and including `60000` since instead of `60+` it's always `<60`. Unless you are also going into minutes.

Comment: I need represent it in **00:00:00** format. If seconds % 60, I want to get **00**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What don't you like about your code ? 
I would have done it like this, but yours looks ok as well...

```
class Duration:
    def __init__(self, milliseconds: int):
        self.__milliseconds = int(milliseconds)

    def seconds(self):
        div, mod = divmod(self.__milliseconds // 1000, 60)
        return mod if div >= 0 else mod-60
```