# What is the pythonic way of converting an integer to 1 if nonzero or 0 otherwise

Tags: python

In C the shortest and obvious way to avoid conditions is:

```
int x = 42;

int oneorzero = !!x;   /* Will give us a 1 if x is non-zero or 0 if zero */
```

Is there a similar way in python?

Comment: `oneorzero = 0 if x == 0 else 1`

Comment: `oneorzero = int(bool(x))` should do the trick

Comment: I'd say `bool(x)` is pretty decent too. It does not give `int` type, but in Python, there is barely any difference. And it does not obstruct clarity much.

Comment: A boolean is an integer. `isinstance(True, int)` will give you `True`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [if x>=1, then 1, otherwise 0, as pure math equation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66516120/if-x-1-then-1-otherwise-0-as-pure-math-equation)

Comment: @asd-tm: I don't think so. I was looking more into a bit operations answer like the C solution I describe, and also negative numbers should return a 1. My intention was to avoid branching operations caused by conditions. But I am not sure if a solution like `int(not(not(x)))` in python is better (in terms of speed) than the solution I accepted.

Comment: @Zenon if you care about speed...don't use Python.

Comment: @Matt: it's for quick prototyping to test different methods, but speed is still important although I admit optimizing such a thing is an overkill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I lately used something like

```
oneorzero = 1 if x else 0
```

which has the benefit that `x` is just tested for its truth value and doesn't necessarily need to be 0 for "false".

Answer (score 2):

you can use [tenrary](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html) operators.

```py
oneorzero = 1 if x else 0
```