# Add 1 to a number while keeping sign in python

Tags: python, list-manipulation

How can I go from:

```
lst = [-2, -4, 5, 7]
```

to:

```
lstmod = [-3, -5, 6, 8]
```

I want to add 1 (or a given `x` value) to each number's magnitude, while keeping the sign. I also want the result to be a list with the same order.

Comment: Hey there Elena! Can you show us what code you've tried, and what output you're getting?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If the number is less than zero, subtract one, otherwise add one.  What is the difficulty?

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehension as follows:

```
lst = [-2, -4, 5, 7]
lst = [(i-1) if i < 0 else (i+1) if i > 0 else 0 for i in lst]

print(lst)
```

**Output:**

```
[-3, -5, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use:

```
lst = [-2, -4, 5, 7]
lstmod = [num+1 if num > 0 else num-1 for num in lst]
```

prints:

```
[-3, -5, 6, 8]
```

Comment: Even shorter `[num + (num > 0 or -1) for num in lst]`

Comment: indeed. But maybe syntactically is simpler to use the one above.

Comment: @OlvinRoght shorter: yes. easier to understand: no.

Comment: @Sören, that's why it's a comment not an answer ;) There're plenty of implicit implementations, here is another one which covers zeros `[num + (num > 0) - (num < 0) for num in lst]`

Answer (score 0):

Slight variation on @Cardstdani's and @sophocles' answer:

```
lst = [-2, -4, 5, 7]
lstmod = [ num + sign(num) for num in lst ]
```

where `sign` is any of the functions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986152/why-doesnt-python-have-a-sign-function) question.